# Cannot GET to a route in Node js and Express.js

Tags: node.js, express

I'm learning Node.js and Express.js.
I'm trying to make a simple API that returns a JSON object but when visit the URL `localhost:4000/api/books`, I'm getting the message: *Cannot GET /api/books*.

```js
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const bookRouter = express.Router();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3500;

bookRouter.route('/books');

bookRouter.get((res, req) =>{
    const response = {Title: 'This is my API', Author: 'XXXX'};
    res.json(response);
  });

app.use('/api',bookRouter);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: You need to remove .router('/books') part and change your get to `bookRouter.get('/books', (res, req) =>{`

Comment: You're also going into some issues because you have `res` and `req` backwards it should be `(req, res)`

Comment: Thanks @VladMiller and mralanlee for your answers my issue was resolved with the combination of your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const bookRouter = express.Router();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3500;


bookRouter.get('/books', (res, req) =>{
    const response = {Title: 'This is my API', Author: 'XXXX'};
    res.json(response);
  });

app.use('/api',bookRouter);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Running on port ${port}`);
});
```